# Create url to download file from angular app

Tags: angular

I have an angular application, which calls backend to generate and download file internally.

But I have to create an url of the angular application, when invoked from external application using a href, file needs to be downloaded, without opening the angular application page.

I could able to create url, download is also happening, by a href is always opening the angular app. I want only download.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: I assume you have a REST API that your application uses to download the files?  Why not just use that endpoint with the external apps?

Comment: Rest api cannot be exposed due to security purpose.

Comment: How is your angular app going to access that file, then?  I assume it's going to make a REST API call to get it - therefore it's already exposed.  You're not hiding anything.  Security through obscurity is no security.  Anyone who knows how to watch network traffic through a browser console will see your backend calls.